# Python - Import module from module child file

Tags: python, import, module

structure:

```
-- tst
------ __init__.py
------ app.py
```

assume execution is as follows:

```
python27 app.py
```

assume `__init__.py` has another import in it, for the sake of question, `import os`

if i execute `app.py` directly, how do I ensure `__init__.py` is executed also? assume there are MANY modules called `tst`, and calling `import tst` from `app.py` is ambiguous (or is it?).

is there something like this:

```
app.py:
import . # import parent folder module, basically tell py27 to execute __init__.py
```

yes, i understand i can solve all my issues by just importing the module like a functioning human being, but this question is a python theory type of question -- i've been thinking about this one...

Answer (score 0):

this may be the dumbest of all solutions, so if anyone can explain how poor this is or if it is the recommended solution, go for it:

```
__init__.py:
print "hello world"

app.py:
import __init__
```

exec: `python27 app.py`

result: `hello world`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this related question (and more importantly, the answers, really):

[At which moment and how often are executed the __init__.py files by python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39452319/at-which-moment-and-how-often-are-executed-the-init-py-files-by-python)

Generally, though, `__init__.py` gets executed only when the package that contains it gets imported.