# How do implicit relative imports work in Python?

Tags: python, module, python-2.x

Assume I have the following files,

```
pkg/
pkg/__init__.py
pkg/main.py # import string
pkg/string.py # print("Package's string module imported")
```

Now, if I run `main.py`, it says `"Package's string module imported"`.

This makes sense and it works as per this statement in this [link](https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html):

> "it will first look in the package's directory"

Assume I modified the file structure slightly (added a core directory):

```
pkg/
pkg/__init__.py
plg/core/__init__.py
pkg/core/main.py # import string
pkg/string.py # print("Package's string module imported")
```

Now, if I run `python core/main.py`, it loads the built-in `string` module.

In the second case too, if it has to comply with the statement "**it will first look in the package's directory"** shouldn't it load the local `string.py` because `pkg` is the "package directory"?

My sense of the term "package directory" is **specifically** the **root folder** of a **collection** of folders with `__init__.py`. So in this case, **pkg** is the "package directory". It is applicable to `main.py` and also files in sub- directories like `core/main.py` because it is part of this "package".

Is this technically correct?

PS: What follows after `#` in the code snippet is the actual content of the file (with no leading spaces).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Packages are directories with a `__init__.py` file, yes, and are loaded as a module **when found on the module search path**. So `pkg` is only a package that you can import and treat as a package **if the parent directory is on the module search path**.

But by running the `pkg/core/main.py` file as a *script*, Python added the `pkg/core` directory to the module search path, not the parent directory of `pkg`. You do have a `__init__.py` file on your module search path now, but that's not what defines a package. You merely have a `__main__` module, there is no package relationship to anything else, and you can't rely on implicit relative imports.

You have three options:

1. Do not run files inside packages as scripts. Put a script file **outside** of your package, and have that import your package as needed. You could put it *next* to the `pkg` directory, or make sure the `pkg` directory is first installed into a directory already on the module search path, or by having your script calculate the right path to add to `sys.path`.
2. Use the [`-m` command line switch](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) to run a module as if it is a script. If you use `python -m pkg.core` Python will look for a `__main__.py` file and run that as a script. The `-m` switch will add the current working directory to your module search path, so you can use that command when you are in the right working directory and everything will work. Or have your package installed in a directory already on the module search path.
3. Have your script add the right directory to the module search path (based on `os.path.absolute(__file__)` to get a path to the current file). Take into account that your script is *always* named `__main__`, and importing `pkg.core.main` would add a second, independent module object; you'd have two separate namespaces.

I also **strongly** advice against using implicit relative imports. You can easily mask top-level modules and packages by adding a nested package or module with the same name. `pkg/time.py` would be found before the standard-library `time` module if you tried to use `import time` inside the `pkg` package. Instead, use the Python 3 model of *explicit* relative module references; add `from __future__ import absolute_import` to all your files, and then use `from . import <name>` to be explicit as to where your module is being imported from.

Comment: Thank You. I think this covers my doubt as well as my original problem I had which is running a script from a module. But one small thing I should have clarified is that by "package directory", I was thinking of the root directory of a collection of folders with `__init__.py`. The reason for that is when I say `zope` package, I mean the root folder usually. It looks like the word "package" is overloaded to mean different things. Probably you want to edit the very first line according to that assumption :-)

Comment: @Nishant: `zope` may be the root folder of the package, but that folder itself is not added to the `sys.path` module search path. You want the *parent directory* of that folder to be on the module search path.

Comment: Thank you @Martijn Pieters, that is a very important point. I didn't know that.

Comment: @Nishant: However, a package can have further nested packages. So `zope.foo` could be a package too, if `zope/foo` is a directory with a `zope/foo/__init__.py` file. So *package directory* is any directory with a `__init__.py` file in it.