# Python "ImportError: cannot import name XYZ" When Importing Functions in Adjacent Sub-Directories of Same Project

Tags: python-3.x, path, organization, sys, subdirectory

**CONTEXT**:
I have a fairly complicated project that's divided into folders, each with a specific purpose. Within each larger folder is a `scripts/` folder, with on average ~5-10 different python files. Each of these python files accesses data within its folder, and often accesses other functions from other files within the same folder.

I'm quite new to Python, have only been using it lightly for about three months.

I'm running Python 3.6.5.

A simplified version of my file tree is below.

**MY OBJECTIVE**:
I need to write one function in one of the sub folders (`Investing/`), that calls functions, in a specific order, from each of the other main folders.

For example, `Investing/scripts/file_name.py` needs to run `Data/scripts/master_update.py`, `Data/scripts/prepare_data.py`, `Training/scripts/prep_data_and_bananas.py` & `Test/scripts/Test_RNN.py` sequentially. And each of these files use data from the rest of their folders.

**MY PROBLEM**: 
My problem is, in every combination I can try and think of and test, I get some form of the error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'XXXXXYYYYYYY'`

My python file is never able to import all the other necessary files correctly. I cannot run multiple different files from multiple different subdirectories each with their own dependencies from one part of one subdirectory inside of the larger folder.

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**: 
I've obviously tried the standard `sys.path.append("path")` and `sys.path.insert(n, "path")` and their accompanying `sys.path.remove("path")`. I've noticed that I am able to import a single file successfully, but I'm never able to import more than one file successfully, even if I remove the path. I've also noticed that if I add a path and then remove the path without calling a function on that path, the imports still work for a single file. However, once I import a file on that path, even if I remove the path afterwards, it doesn't work again. I presume this has something to do with how python handles `sys.path`.

**WHAT I SEEK**:
I hope this has been clear enough. I am more than happy to answer any clarification questions. If someone could even point me towards a good resources to truly learn how `sys.path`, and `python import XYZ` works, I would super appreciate it.

```html
|-- Data/
|   |-- .DS_Store
|   |-- coin_list.csv
|   |-- crypto/
|   |   |-- .DS_Store
|   |   |-- master.json
|   |-- news/
|   |   |-- .DS_Store
|   |   |-- master.json
|   |-- scripts/
|   |   |-- .DS_Store
|   |   |-- generate_news_data.py
|   |   |-- generate_normalized_crypto_data.py
|   |   |-- generate_raw_crypto_data.py
|   |   |-- global_vars.py
|   |   |-- helpers.py
|   |   |-- init_folders.py
|   |   |-- master_update.py
|   |   |-- prepare_data.py
|   |   |-- upload_s3.py
|   |-- training_data/
|   |   |-- .DS_Store
|   |   |-- master_news.json
|   |-- twitter/
|-- Investing/
|   |-- .DS_Store
|   |-- keys/
|   |   |-- firstkey.key
|   |-- scripts/
|   |   |-- .DS_Store
|   |   |-- execute_investment.py
|   |   |-- main_trader.py
|   |   |-- master_invester.py
|-- Testing/
|   |-- .DS_Store
|   |-- Net_Prediction_data/
|   |   |-- .DS_Store
|   |-- scripts/
|   |   |-- .DS_Store
|   |   |-- .gitattributes
|   |   |-- display_predict_data.py
|   |   |-- global_tests.py
|   |   |-- save_net_predict_data.py
|   |   |-- Test_RNN.py
|   |-- top_models/
|   |   |-- .DS_Store
|-- Training/
|   |-- .DS_Store
|   |-- models/
|   |   |-- .DS_Store
|   |-- performance_charts/
|   |   |-- .DS_Store
|   |-- Prepped_Training_Data/
|   |   |-- .DS_Store
|   |-- scripts/
|   |   |-- .DS_Store
|   |   |-- csv_saver.py
|   |   |-- global_vars.py
|   |   |-- helpers.py
|   |   |-- Market Performance.py
|   |   |-- prep_data_and_bananas.py
|   |   |-- read_performance_data.py
|   |   |-- RNN_Single.py
|   |   |-- RNN_Single_constants.py
```

Comment: For starters, I don't see an `__init__.py` anywhere. Read this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48304317/how-do-implicit-relative-imports-work-in-python) and these docs: [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) and [import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).

Comment: I'll do that. Good suggestion, thanks.

Comment: @pstatix I added __init__.py's, as described in this article: https://timothybramlett.com/How_to_create_a_Python_Package_with___init__py.html, but the problem persists. When importing the files within the scripts folders, they can't find their dependencies.