# The dot in module import (python 3.x)

Tags: python, python-3.x

For what i can use the "." in import module. I meet it in sklearn library. It looks like:

```
from .externals import six
```

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48304317/how-do-implicit-relative-imports-work-in-python) SO post and [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/).

Answer (score -1):

The . is a shortcut that tells it search in current package before rest of the PYTHONPATH. So, if a same-named module Recipe exists somewhere else in your PYTHONPATH, it won't be loaded.

Comment: *"search in current package before rest of the PYTHONPATH"* That is incorrect. A `.` import is a relative import; the PYTHONPATH isn't searched *at all*.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong on so many levels..