# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model' using PyVCF in Python. 3.11.3

Tags: python, module, vcf-variant-call-format

I running Python 3.11.3 from my windows, and try to use PyVCF module.
I checked my Python version in my pc and I found no double installment, only 1 python version installed. I have sublime text and VS Code in my pc.

but when I try to import I got this

import vcf
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\Users\LeNOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\vcf_*init*_.py", line 9, in 
from vcf.parser import Reader, Writer
File "C:\Users\LeNOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\vcf\parser.py", line 25, in 
from model import _Call, _Record, make_calldata_tuple
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'

Answer (score 0):

do you know which version of PyVCF you have installed? Unfortunately, the repository that points to PyVCF on PyPI is dead since 2017, so there is no python3 compatibility. There are a few forks and workarounds which fixed minor issues that appeared during install.

The error you got comes from the usage of `implicit relative references` which is not allowed in python3 anymore, in this case functions where imported from a submodule `model.py` using:

```
from model import _Call, _Record, make_calldata_tuple
```

Python3 looks for a main-level module called `model`, not installed; the correct python3 way to do this would be:

```
from .model import _Call, _Record, make_calldata_tuple
```

the background why this behaviour was changed in python3 is nicely explained in [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48304390/16625506)

To solve your problem, you might want to have a look at [PyVCF3](https://github.com/dridk/PyVCF3), which should replace legacy PyVCF.