# What code runs when importing from a module within a subpackage?

Tags: python-packaging

Assume that

- `sys.path` includes `/Some/Path`
- Package `/Some/Path/PkgP1` contains subpackage
  `/Some/Path/PkgP1/SbPkgP1_S1`
- Module `/Some/Path/PkgP1/ModP1_M1.py` contains `FuncP1_M1_F1`
- Module `/Some/Path/PkgP1/SbPkgP1_S1/ModP1_S1_M1.py` contains
  function `FuncP1_S1_M1_F1`

Here is an ASCII illustration

```
/Some/Path/
 |
 +- PkgP1/
     |
     +- __init__.py
     |
     +- ModP1_M1.py (contains function FuncP1_M1_F1)
     |
     +- SbPkgP1_S1/
         |
         +- __init__.py
         |
         +- ModP1_S1_M1.py (contains function FuncP1_S1_M1_F1)
```

[This Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27144872) says that
each of the following causes both `/Some/Path/Pkg1/__ini__.py` and
`/Some/Path/Pkg1/ModP1_M1.py` to run:

- `import Pkg1/ModP1_M1`
- `from Pkg1/ModP1_M1 import FuncP1_M1_F1`

Which of the following (if any) also causes
`/Some/Path/Pkg1/__ini__.py` to run?

1. `import PkgP1.SbPkgP1_S1`
2. `import PkgP1.SbPkgP1_S1.ModP1_S1_M1`
3. `from PkgP1.SbPkgP1_S1 import ModP1_S1_M1`
4. `from PkgP1.SbPkgP1_S1.ModP1_S1_M1 import FuncP1_S1_M1_F1`

Additionally, do all of these also cause `/Some/Path/PkgP1/SbPkgP1_S1/__ini__.py` to run?